# Javascript remove object from array using object variable

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to use arrays and for demonstration purposes I have condensed the code using points as examples. I want to create a point and push it to array and after doing stuff I want to remove the point from the array.

```
var PointArray = [];
function CreatePoint(X,Y){
    this.x=X;
    this.y=Y;
    PointArray.push(this);
}
function RemovePoint(PointObject){
     //????
}
var xPoint = CreatePoint(10,10);
//do stuff
RemovePoint(xPoint);
```

I was looking at the ‍`Array.prototype` manual and `PointArray.Splice` seems like a the closest but feels messy since it wants indexs. Anyone have a clean way remove objects from array to shove into function `RemovePoint`?

Comment: Slice is how you do it unless you want to use a library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the index of something in an array, use `indexOf`:

```
function RemovePoint(PointObject){
  const index = PointArray.indexOf(PointObject);
  PointArray.splice(index, 1); // remove one item at index "index"
}
```

But if you're doing something like this, you might consider using a `Set` instead, which might be more appropriate if you want a collection, but the index of each object doesn't actually matter - then, you could just call `PointSet.delete(PointObject);`:

```js
const PointSet = new Set();
function CreatePoint(X,Y){
  this.x=X;
  this.y=Y;
  PointSet.add(this);
}
function RemovePoint(PointObject){
  PointSet.delete(PointObject);
}
console.log(PointSet.size);
const xPoint = new CreatePoint(10,10);
console.log(PointSet.size);
RemovePoint(xPoint);
console.log(PointSet.size);
```

As comment notes, make sure to use `new` when calling a constructor like `CreatePoint`.

Comment: Ah. I didn't realize i could do that. let me go read the doc on it.

Comment: @MoonEater916 Works just fine for me - see edit. Calling `CreatePoint` increases the `Set`'s size to 1, and then calling `RemovePoint` reduces the size to 0.

Comment: ya doing a test xPoint is undefined because I didn't put "new" in the line "var xPoint = new CreatePoint(10,10);" Works Great! Thanks @MarkMeyer

Answer (score 0):

Why not use filter to remove elements from PointArray

```
var PointArray = [];
function CreatePoint(X,Y){
    this.x=X;
    this.y=Y;
    PointArray.push(this);
}
function RemovePoint(PointObject){
  PointArray = PointArray.filter(singlePoint=>!(singlePoint.x==PointObject.x && singlePoint.y==PointObject.y));
}
var xPoint = new CreatePoint(10,10);
var yPoint = new CreatePoint(20,20);
//do stuff
console.log(PointArray);
RemovePoint(xPoint);
console.log(PointArray);
```

Comment: In your particular example, because they don't want to remove all points with a specific x/y value, they want to remove a specific entry.

Comment: But even using a set would not allow to keep duplicates. So no two points have same x and y value

Comment: Depends on how equality is defined, but a set isn't necessarily the right approach-we don't know because the full problem isn't defined.

Comment: For deleting an item from a set that is a collection of points, the only equality check would be x and y. So will be the insertion check.

Comment: With the current object definition, yes, but that would be a bad way to generally represent points, since it's perfectly valid to have distinct points with the same coordinates. But that's orthogonal to the question, which is how to remove a specific array entry, which may or may not be unique-we simply don't know the problem's parameters.